# Transferring data between non-nested components

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Basically , What I desire is to transfer data b/w components.

I have one angular2 component on master page for partial view of login -

```
<loginpartial></loginpartial>
```

This is initially rendered through this html template with **child component**-

```
<ul [hidden]="!item.isAuthenticated">
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Hello! {{item.userName}}</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">LogOff</a></li>
</ul>
<ul [hidden]="item.isAuthenticated">
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Hello! User</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Log In</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Child Component -**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'loginpartial',
    templateUrl: '../Templates/LoginPartial.html'
})

export class LoginPartialComponent implements OnInit {
    public item: any = { isAuthenticated: false, userName: ' ' }
    constructor() {
        this.item.isAuthenticated = false;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.item.isAuthenticated = false;
    }
}
```

I hope this makes sense till now. Now What my need is as soon as user is logged in , I want to get username in this partial view transferred from parent component.

**Parent Component**

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {LoginPartialComponent} from '../loginpartialview/loginpartial.component.ts';
import {SharedService} from '../sharedService/app.sharedService.ts';

@Component({
    selector: 'loginmodel',
    templateUrl: '../Templates/Login.html',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    providers: [LoginPartialComponent,SharedService]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    item: any = {
        isAuthenticated: false, userName: ' '
    };
    constructor(private sharedService: SharedService,
        private loginComp: LoginPartialComponent) {
    }

    onSubmit(item: any): void {
        if (this.myForm.valid) {
            var userObject = {
                email: item.email,
                password: item.password
            };
            this.sharedService.getLogin(userObject).map(response => response.json())
                .subscribe(
                data => this.handleResult(data),
                error => console.log(error)
                );
        }
    }

    private handleResult(data) {
        if (data.success) {
            this.item.isAuthenticated = true;
            this.item.userName = data.userName;
            this.item = this.loginComp.item;
        }
        else {

        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from this **parent component** when `onSubmit` function is called which is my login form submission I am calling `handleResult` that is setting data from ajax call from the shared service.

This is not letting the child component - `LoginPartialComponent` refresh. I tried with `@Input()` type parameters too but didn't help me.

**Update** -

As @Camaron said in his answer I created a dependency for this login purpose only with event emitters. But this doesn't work.

**LoginPartialComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {LoginPartialModel} from '../loginpartialview/loginpartial.model.ts';
import {SharedService} from '../sharedService/app.sharedService.ts';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Component({
    selector: 'loginpartial',
    templateUrl: '../Templates/LoginPartial.html',
    providers: [SharedService]
})

export class LoginPartialComponent {
    item: LoginPartialModel = new LoginPartialModel();
    constructor(private service: SharedService) {
        this.service.onLoginSuccess.subscribe((loginData: any) => this.item == loginData.item);
    }

}
```

**LoginComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {SharedService} from '../sharedService/app.sharedService.ts';

@Component({
    selector: 'loginmodel',
    templateUrl: '../Templates/Login.html',
    providers: [SharedService]
})
export class LoginComponent {

    constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {
    }

    onSubmit(item: any): void {
            var userObject = {
                email: item.email,
                password: item.password
            };
            this.sharedService.getLogin(userObject).map(response => response.json())
                .subscribe(
                data => this.handleResult(data),
                error => console.log(error)
                );
    }
    private handleResult(data) {
        if (data.success) {
            this.close();
            this.sharedService.onLoginSuccess.emit(data);
        }
        else {

        }
    }
}
```

**Shared Service (dependency)**

```
import { Component, Injectable, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

    onLoginSuccess: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
    constructor() {
    }

    notifyLoginSuccess(item: any): void {
        this.onLoginSuccess.emit({ item: item });
    }
}
```

This didn't work.

Comment: Inside of your `handleResult` function, shouldn't be `this.loginComp.item = this.item;` instead of `this.item = this.loginComp.item;` ?

Comment: @camaron, yes should be this. But this won't change it there.

Comment: had you tried to remove the changeDetection strategy from both components?

Comment: @camaron, Its actually these components are not nested. both are standalone. 
Do you think removing changeDetection would help?

Comment: Just check this line `this.service.onLoginSuccess.subscribe((loginData: any) => this.item == loginData.item)` there is a double = should be just one =.

Comment: no man this is not working.

Comment: @camaron, Can you join me here please - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126823/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-40219356-transferring-data-between-non-nested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a service to establish this communication `subscribe` the `LoginPartialComponent`.

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

    onLoginSuccess: EventEmitter<any>() = new EventEmitter<any>();

    constructor() {
    }

    notifyLoginSuccess(item:any):void {
        this.onLoginSuccess.emit({item: item});
    }

}
```

And then **Inject** this service on both components.
In your `LoginPartialComponent` subscribe to this service event.

```
constructor(public loginService:LoginService) {
    this.loginService.onLoginSuccess.subscribe((loginData: any) => this.item = loginData.item);
}
```

Then in your `handleResult` function make a call to `loginService.notifyLoginSuccess` and send the `item`.

With this solution you can remove the dependency of your components so the **`LoginComponent`** don't need to know that there is a **`LoginPartialComponent`**.

Comment: Thanks for your time but the fact is these components are neither parents nor children.
So this is not a case of nested components. Components here are standalone.

Comment: With this example that doesn't matters, this solution works for any kind of relation between components and for those ones without relation. Add this service on your ngmodule providers to use the same sevice instance on both components.

Comment: I tried it just as you said. Let me edit question . I think it is not calling constructor of loginComponent.

Comment: `this.sharedService.notifyLoginSuccess(data);` this called shared service event but not that one which is in constructor of partial component.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with the injected service to the component, have you removed the providers: [SharedService] on both components and added the SharedService as a global provider right?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the preferred Angular-fanatic way would be to make a function in a component (or service I guess, though I guess it's kind of all just components now) Observable and subscribe to it.

I think this post lays it out well:

http://mean.expert/2016/05/21/angular-2-component-communication/

Also note Input and Output properties for parent -> child and vice versa communication.

Comment: Thanks for your time but the fact is these components are neither parents nor children.
So this is not a case of nested components. Components here are standalone.

Comment: The solution isn't just for parent and children. Take a look at the link, it discusses solutions for both.